# Chat Logs using Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have included **middleware** to log the chats in firebase db. Now I am able to call the middleware once after the user sends some text to the bot then after bot sends the data to the user. In the previous version *bot framework v3* the **activity** payload will change the ***message.text and from and to*** as 
**user-bot/bot-user**. But now in ***bot framework v4*** when the bot sends message/response to the user I can't find the data sent anywhere in the payload.
Is there a way to save the data from bot-user. Please suggest me any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get in the middle of activities being sent outwards from the bot from a piece of middleware you would want to hook into the `ITurnContext::OnSendActivities` like so:

```
public class MyActivityLoggingMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // log incoming activity from turnContext.Activity here

        // Hook the turn context's OnSendActivities
        turnContext.OnSendActivities(HandleSendActivities);

        await next(cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<ResourceResponse[]> HandleSendActivities(ITurnContext turnContext, List<Activity> activities, Func<Task<ResourceResponse[]>> next)
    {
        // log activities being sent here

        return await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DevaNarayanan No problem! How about an upvote or marking as the answer to help other people out in the future? 

Comment: already did but my reputation is less than 15 thats why commented :laugh: